# Why node *left,*right and not node* left,right?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, syntax

The type of left and right is node* so like other types they should be declared as node* left,right; Example int a,b;

Comment: So that you can write `int a, *b = &a`.

Comment: Because the standard says so. Are you interested in the history behind this syntax decision?

Comment: How did this get +3 ??

Comment: because the pointer somehow belongs to the variable, so it should be specified as: `int *left, *right, nopointer_just_int`

Comment: `node* left, right;` is same as `node *left, *right;` throught first one prefered. read a book first, its basic.

Comment: @rootTraveller, can you back up that assertion?

Comment: @rootTraveller Are you sure?

Comment: Variable declaration syntax is not `typename varname1, varname2`. The type information doesn't all go in one block on the left. (Arguably, it should have; C variable declaration syntax is confusing.)

Comment: @rootTraveller That is 100% wrong.  `node* left, right;` is the same as `node* left; node right;`

Comment: @NathanOliver I did not get it, would you share some links ?

Comment: @rootTraveller Just look at the answers on the question this is closed as a duplicate of.

Comment: @NathanOliver `node* left, right;` from here how do you guys getting this  `node right;`???

Comment: @rootTraveller Would this link be good enough: https://ideone.com/sI2j2v ?

Comment: And the reason for spamming tags of two different languages is?

Comment: @rootTraveller The pointer is attached to the variable name, not the type name.  In `node* left, right;` `right` is not a pointer.  That's just how pointers and references work.

Comment: @rootTraveller read a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) please.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I got it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pick one way or the other, and this way is less awful. For an example of how awful the other way would be, compare:

```
int a[10], b[20], c[30];
```

to

```
int[10] a;
int[20] b;
int[30] c;
```

Comment: Many would contest the assertion that this way is less awful.

Comment: True, but the point is that it's a choice between two schemes that each have their advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: `int[10] a;` What?

Comment: @NathanOliver That's how you'd declare an array if the rule was the one the OP suggests. Just like `int* a, b;` instead of `int *a, *b;` you'd have `int[10] a, b;` instead of `int a[10], b[10];`. Unless you're suggesting something even more bizarre.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Oh.  I didn't get that you were showing how it would look if it was attached to the type.

Answer (score 0):

When programming in C, if you get in the habit of attaching the * to the variable names it will make more sense to you.

```
int *i,j;
```

i is an int* and j is an int.

Comment: This logic breaks with `decltype(i) k`.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I didn't realize the question was also tagged c++